# Add sample info to dataset in PCA (R)

Tags: r, pca, autoplot

Im a biologist, not a programmer so please be gentle.

So I have a dataset that looks like

```
Genes  Patient1   Patient2   Patient3
A          324      433         343
B          431       342        124
Z          232       234        267
```

then I have the sample sheet where it contains sample info like:

```
Patient1 - Healthy
Patient2 - Disease
Patient3 - Healthy
```

I am using:

```
library(ggfortify)
df <- dataset
pca_res <- prcomp(df, scale. = TRUE)

autoplot(pca_res)
```

Then I want to do

```
autoplot(pca_res, data = ?, colour = '?')
```

I wish to use the info from the sample sheet to color my PCA based on the state (healthy/disease) using the autoplot function. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I really think you should read a tutorial or explain more clearly what you want to do. Are you you want the patients in columns?

Answer (score 1):

First, I would create a complete data.frame with all information available.

For example, you will need to create this kind of data.frame :

```
df=structure(list(A = c(324, 433, 343), B = c(431, 342, 124), Z = c(232, 
234, 267), Status = c("Healthy", "Disease", "Healthy")), row.names = c("Patient1", 
"Patient2", "Patient3"), class = "data.frame")
```

After, you could use the `factoextra` package that is very handy for plotting PCA :

```
pca_res <- prcomp(df, scale. = TRUE)
library(factoextra)
fviz_pca_ind(pca_res, habillage=df$Status)
```

You can check the `fviz_pca_ind` documentation to modify the color thereafter

**Edit :**

To create the whole dataframe from your 2 datasets :

1)Take your first dataframe and put the first column as rownames

```
rownames(df)=df$Genes
df=df[,-1] #remove the gene column in order to keep only the values
```

2)Formatting your second dataframe
You should format it to havethe same columns as df (Patient1, Patient2,...) with for each one the disease status, that you will call df2

```
df2
rownames(df2)=c("Status")

Patient1   Patient2   Patient3
Healthy   Disease   Healthy
```

We don't know your data so you have to perform this by your own

3)Then you rbind df and df2

```
df3=rbind(df,df2)
df3=data.frame(t$df)
```

and then your perform PCA with df3

Comment: Hi, I would do this but the actual data contains 10,999 observations so that's impossible to do manually one by one, I mean the first part

Comment: You have the `rbind` function that can do this, supposing we keep the 1st dataframe in your post df only with genes values and gene names in rownames, and you have a second dataframe df2 with patients info in columns, your new dataframe will be `rbind(df,df2)`